# how to check alert view displayed in xctest case in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I need to show alert on screen for any validation case and is working fine. But when working with `XCTest` I am not able to detect if alert is shown. How can I check `UIAlertView` or `UIAlertController` in `XCTest` case in `Xcode`. please give any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addUIInterruptionMonitor` to handle `UIAlertController` in `XCTest`.

```
let handler = addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "alert handler") { (alert: XCUIElement) -> Bool in
    let ok = alert.buttons["OK"]
    XCTAssertTrue(ok.exists, "OK button doesn't exist")
    ok.tap()
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me. can you check once and confirm.